# Get ranking of list elements using loops and if-statement

Tags: r

Each alphabet gets 3 points for each first-choice ranking, 2 points for each second-choice ranking and 1 point for each third-choice ranking

```
Rank(list(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), c("B", "C", "D", "A")))
```

In this example, A get 3 points, B gets 5 points, C gets 3 points, D gets 1 point

So the winner is B.

How do I define it by just using loops and if-statements so that I can get the result as:

```
Rank(list(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), c("B", "C", "D", "A")))

[[1]]
[1] "B"

[[2]]
[1] 3 5 3 1
```

Comment: `rowSums(sapply(l, function(x) (4 - as.integer(factor(x, unique(x))))[order(x)]))`

Comment: This is for the OPs homework assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need loop or if statements for this.

One solution might be to turn your list into vector and create single `data.table` with ranking:

```
# Create list
foo <- list(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
            c("B", "C", "D", "A"))

library(data.table)
# Create long object with ranking
# Sum ranking by value (letter in list)
result <- melt(data.table(unlist(foo), x = 3:0), "x")[, sum(x), value]
```

> ```
>    value V1
> 1:     A  3
> 2:     B  5
> 3:     C  3
> 4:     D  1
> ```

```
# Solution wanted by OP
list(result[which.max(V1), value], result$V1)
```

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1] "B"
>
> [[2]]
> [1] 3 5 3 1
> ```

Comment: My homework specified that I can only use ifs and loops, any hints? Thanks

Comment: @A.Smith Think for yourself and question authority